# use zip with two lists

Tags: python, list, zip, iteration

I am trying to iterate through two lists one with 76 files and the other with 76 variables to read the files to. 
I figured I can iterate through them with zip(list1, list2) but for some reason it is not working.
Here is what I am doing:

```
list1=['file1', 'file2', 'file3']
list2=['v1','v2','v3']
for i,j in zip(list1,list2):
    j=pyfits.getdata(i)       #just trying to read a FITS file
```

When I do the same thing with print instead it works well:

```
list1=['file1', 'file2', 'file3']
list2=['v1','v2','v3']
for i,j in zip(list1,list2):
    print i, j
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
j=pyfits.getdata(i)
```

This line doesn't store the data to the variable whose name is stored in `j`. Rather, it stores the data to the variable `j`. What you want is instead to make a list of the data:

```
data = [pyfits.getdata(filename) for filename in list1]
```

This will create a list where `data[0]` is the data from the first file, `data[1]` is the data from the second, etc.

Answer (score 2):

I assume you're trying to assign the strings in `list2` to the array that `pyfits.getdata()` returns. However, `list2` contains strings, and you can't assign an array to a string this way. There are some hacky ways to do it, but it's not good practice in Python. I'd recommend using a dictionary, where the strings in `list2` can be the keys in the dictionary.

Here's an example:

```
data = {}
list1=['file1', 'file2', 'file3']
list2=['v1','v2','v3']
for i,j in zip(list1,list2):
    data[j] = pyfits.getdata(i)
```

Then you can access your data with `data[v1]`, `data[v2]`, etc.

Comment: You can also use a dictionary comprehension, akin to @user2357112 's answer

Answer (score 0):

You may use `map` function:

```
list2 = map(pyfits.getdata,list1)
zip(list1,list2) #not needed here
```

and after create pretty dict

```
di = dict(zip(list1,list2))
```

`di` will be structured like `{filename1:data1,filename2,data2}`